# Non-type templates - which types are allowed?

Tags: c++, templates

According to the standard, this should compile:

```
struct Y {};
template<const Y& y> struct Z {};


int main(){
    Y y;
    Z<y> z;  // ok: no conversion and cv-qualification conversion
}
```

(it's taken from - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

But, it doesn't, giving this error: error: the value of ‘y’ is not usable in a constant expression

What am I missing?

Comment: `Z<Y>` not `Z<y>`

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant No, `Z<y>` is correct here.

Comment: The cppreference example doesn't have `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking a reference to a local object, which is not a constant expression. If `y` was a global variable, [it'd work just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16a628df51226bcc).